# Finding a volume of a region defined by |x-y+z|+|y-z+x|+|z-x+y|=1

Tags: integration, volume

Find the volume of the region definded by |x-y+z|+|y-z+x|+|z-x+y|=1.

I'm having trouble approaching this problem. Could someone maybe give me a hint or a solution, it would be so helpful.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Graph it using Geogebra or a similar software and try to write the boundaries of the region as an iterated integral.

Comment: Surely the volume is zero? Did you mean $\le 1$? You can write the above as $\|A x\|_1 = 1$ where $A$ is invertible and $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @adriana Maybe a variable change like $t=x-y+z$, $u=y-z+x$, $v=z-x+y$ could help, but then you'll have to multiply by [the jacobian](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jacobian+of+%28x-y%2Bz%2C+y-z%2Bx%2Cz%E2%88%92x%2By%29). The resulting answer will be $\frac{16}{3]$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @copper.hat , I copied the problem from one of previous math exams(engineering level). We are currently learning about multiple integrals and we are supposed to use them solving this problem. But I have no idea how to start. Its much more complex than the other problems we've been solving.

Comment: @Integrand thank you, I will try and do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's find the volume of the related region

$$|x|+|y|+|z| \leq 1$$

By the symmetry of the region we can reduce it to an integral in the first octant only

$$\iiint_EdV = 8 \iiint_{E\:\cap\:\text{First Octant}} dV$$

Then setting up and doing the integral is not that hard

$$ = 8\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} \int_0^{1-x-y} dz\:dy\:dx = 8\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2} - x + \frac{1}{2}x^2\:dx = \frac{4}{3}$$

Now how does this help us with this problem? We can use the substitution

$$\begin{cases}u = x-y+z \\ v = x+y-z \\ w = -x+y+z \\ \end{cases} \implies J^{-1} = \begin{vmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 \\ \end{vmatrix} = 4$$

Thus with this change of variables we get that

$$\iiint_{|x-y+z|+|y-z+x|+|z-x+y|\leq 1} dV = \iiint_{|u|+|v|+|w|\leq 1}\frac{1}{4} \:dV' = \frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Only the determinant seems to be [$4$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det+%7B%7B1%2C+-1%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+1%2C+-1%7D%2C+%7B-1%2C+1%2C+1%7D%7D)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin thank you for the correction! I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you visualize the region:

[image]